# Sikuli API not registering typing commands correctly

Tags: java, automation, sikuli, sikuli-script

I'm using the Sikuli API to develop a repetitive task that involves some GUI components. So far I've been able to recognize images, but when I try use the type command it does not pay attention to the case of my string and simply types everything in lower case. The paste function does not work either.

I've tried using Java's Robot class too, but it doesn't simulate key presses correctly. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong -- or perhaps have any clues that might lead me in the right direction?

```
 Screen s = new Screen();
 s.click("img/searchbar.png");
 s.wait(2.5);
 s.type("v",KeyModifier.CMD);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you mean that if you do something like `s.type("abcABC")`, it will all be typed in lower case?

Comment: Yep. I'm actually trying to circumvent this by executing some applescript in parallel, but it's still not registering that I'm combining a keystroke for some reason.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you using the original sikuli or sikuli API project which is a completely different project(https://github.com/sikuli/sikuli-api)?